# How-to close an application in BlackBerry PlayBook?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

When I launch an app (default Browser for example), it seems that there is no way to exit except reboot. I'm using PlayBook emulator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swipe up from the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 5):

Use a "bottom-swipe" gesture (starting in the bottom bezel region, drag up into the screen area).  The app window will minimize itself, at which point you can click on its X widget to close it, or drag it up to "toss it" away.

The basic gestures are described in the [Getting Started guides](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25068/Gestures_1398111_11.jsp), which all new developers should read (along with the [associated docs](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Adobe+AIR+Development+Guides+and+API+Reference), including the UI Guidelines and Development Guide).  All these bezel gestures are reserved for the OS itself, except the "top-swipe" which is reserved for context menus and such in the apps themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to go to home page and swipe down from top of screen for top menu.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this for more detailed information about using the PlayBook simulator.

http://savagelook.com/blog/portfolio/blackberry-playbook-simulator-tips